# crop out dark area from an image with shallow stripes on it

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to remove the dark area of an image that has some shallow stripes. To be clear, I am attaching the picture:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjEIp.jpg) [threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XLKK.jpg)

I tried threshold it with a gray level by doing`_, th = cv2.threshold(gray, 67, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)`, but I got an unsatisfied result.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: You aren't giving us much information to work with. Do you know anything more about the inage? Is the dark area maybe always on the right side? Are there maybe always 3 regions? Or more? Or less? Are the regions always rectangular?

Comment: Hi Mark, the dark area could be on left or right. There are basically three regions, and the dart area is the biggest, but the size of each region is not fixed. The image regions are actually from the projection of a cylindrical battery, so it looks like rectangular but not exactly because the projection direction varies a little bit for each battery. I would be great if we could somehow get the boundary between dark and shallow area.

Comment: The upper part of the gray-ish area partly has lower intensity values than the lower part of the black-ish area. That'll be a huge problem for finding an appropriate threshold for masking the black-ish area. Please provide a sketch or similar of the desired output.

Comment: I basically want to crop out the dark area because my ROI is the shallow part on the left  of this image. More specifically, the shallow part has two areas, and my ROI is the one in the middle of the whole picture. So, if we could find the border between the shallow and dart area, I would crop the image and fill the left over area with background color.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the mean (or the sum) across all the rows, using `np.mean(image, axis=1)` and likewise down the columns, using `np.mean(image, axis=0)`, you'll get this which should enable you to find the edges of the regions as long as they are rectangular-ish and aligned with the edges of the image.

[image]

Comment: I used the similar method to crop the original image(X direction), and I could definitely do the same for Y direction. I could probably do this for each row or column as well, but the challenge is: how to group the data to find the splitting points based on the value(gray scale). Because we are dealing with thousands of images with different gray scales, it is hard to use fix values to group the data.